# Cloudbees Jenkins Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin configuration hardcoded to use Cloud?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, cloudbees

I get a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to connect the Bitbucket Source Plugin to my on-prem Bitbucket Datacentre (Server) installation.

If I use my own Bitbucket.org cloud account credentials I get a different error,  leading me to believe that even though I've configured the plugin to use a Bitbucket Server, it's still reaching out to the Cloud bitbucket(.org).

Versions:
Jenkins: 2.110
Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin: 2.2.11
Bitbucket (datacentre): v5.7.1

Following the documentation https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#bitbucket There is no Advanced button to configure the Bitbucket Server/Cloud.  The only configuration I found was in the Configure System [Jenkins] section;

Gobal Configuration:

Bitbucket Endpoints

- Bitbucket Server
- Name My Bitbucket Git
- Server URL   https://mygit.net
- Manage hooks [no]

In my multibranch pipeline, I've removed the Git source and added the Bitbucket Source.

Configured it with a rest API account for my Bitbucket instance.  I've even added this user to the admin group
Configured the Owner as a project within my Bitbucket instance

None of the other boxes let me populate them.

Running the manual scan results in the below error:

com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.api.BitbucketRequestException: HTTP request error. Status: 401: Unauthorized.

I have personal Bitbucket.org credentials.  If I use these instead (without changing any other configuration), I get the following error instead:

```
[Mon Apr 30 12:32:02 UTC 2018] Starting branch indexing...
Connecting to https://bitbucket.org using xxx.xxx@myemail.com/****** (My Atlassian Cloud)
ERROR: [Mon Apr 30 12:32:03 UTC 2018] Could not fetch branches from source 3f72008d-bf57-4ee3-abd4-1d2c6fb07c6e
```

Attention drawn to the log entry: Connecting to **https://bitbucket.org**

I've restarted Jenkins multiple times, thinking that the global configuration is being cached incorrectly in some way.

I'm now at the point where I believe that either I've configured the plugin in the wrong place and I can't find the correct place.  Or the plugin isn't honouring the configuration and it's hardcoded (?) to always use the cloud bitbucket.

Answer (score 4):

Posting a solution even though this is an old thread, as I came across the exact same issue recently (and a potential solution).

My setup was:

- Bitbucket Server v6.7.1
- Jenkins 2.190.2
- Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin 2.5.0

And I was seeing the same **Could not refresh actions for navigator com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.BitbucketSCMNavigator@d0235a2 com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.api.BitbucketRequestException: HTTP request error. Status: 401** everytine Jenkins tried to scan the BitBucket Team/Project pipeline (on the BitBucket server).

**SOLUTION:** This was hidden in the Jenkins configuration itself (i.e. **Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System**)

- Configure the **Bitbucket Endpoints** section with the essential Bitbucket Server details like **Name**, **Server URL**, and **Credentials**. Other properties in this section are optional.
- Scroll down the page (**Jenkins > Configure System**) and look for another section called **Bitbucket Server Violations Server Defaults**. Make sure that the **Credentials** and the **Base URL** property values match the **Credentials** and **Server URL** values from the **Bitbucket Endpoints** section. Once these values were entered (and matched), the above error was fixed and the Bitbucket Team/Project pipeline scan started to connect to the Bitbucket server successfully.